# Mustafar Sith Holocron

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith, holocron

Talking about the [Mustafar Sith Holocron](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mustafar_Sith_holocron)... we know only a fragment of the data:

> ...was going according to plans until yesterday. The weakling Jedi has
>   some sort of secret weapon and I can feel the effects of it already
>   now. I can sense that our master knows what it is, but he has revealed
>   nothing, only forced us to press on even harder...

Who is talking? What he/she is talking about? What secret weapon?

Comment: *"After finding the mining droid and recovering the holocron, the player had to fight several attacking Trinity Assassins and return to Q4P3. The holocron could be activated every 60 minutes and enhanced the combat capability of the player for a short time."* - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mustafar_Sith_holocron Could the power-up bonus be what he's referring to?